# Failed to connect from SQL Server database to MS Power BI Desktop

Tags: sql-server, powerbi-desktop

I want to connect my Power BI Desktop from my server. But it fails to connect and [throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ryaY.png) by entering the following information of my server

> Microsoft SQL: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=457; handshake=29589;

[image: Screenshot]

I also checked the below advanced option. But the error remains same.

Comment: The primary reason for this error may be passing the wrong credentials like server name, user id or password.

Comment: Please read the how-to-ask and look at some other questions to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Wrong server name? Wrong port? Firewall configuration?

Comment: What is Firewall configuration?

Answer (score 0):

By using correct server name and password without port name. I have connected my MS SQL with Power BI.

The main issue was that i was using username and password of server.